# C++ syntax issues applied to the ROS fram

Tags: c++, ros

I wrote a subscriber function to subscribe to a string-type message topic.
The first version of the program showed the prompt "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" and could not be executed.
Then I modified the program according to the chatGPT instructions, and the second version can be executed.

The programs are as below:
----Version one：

```
# include "ros/ros.h"
# include "std_msgs/String.h"

class NameSubscriber
{
private:
    ros::Subscriber sub;
    ros::NodeHandle nh;
public:
    NameSubscriber(std::string _topic, int queue_size)
    : nh(ros::NodeHandle()),
    sub(nh.subscribe(_topic, queue_size, &NameSubscriber::Callback, this))
{
}
    
    void Callback(const std_msgs::String::ConstPtr& msg)
    {
        ROS_INFO("### Success get publisher");
        ROS_INFO("I get the message is: %s, at: %f", msg->data.c_str(),ros::Time::now().toSec());
    } 
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "name_s");
    NameSubscriber name_sub("sub_Anthony",100);
    ros::spin();
    return 0;
}
```

----Version two（only show the modified part）：

```
public:
    NameSubscriber(std::string _topic, int queue_size)
    : nh()
    {
        sub = nh.subscribe(_topic, queue_size, &NameSubscriber::Callback, this);
    }
    
...
```

I have two questions:

1. Why is the reason cause of "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"?
2. I don't understand what's different in the way the "sub" is built.

I appreciate any suggestions.

I modified the way to build "sub" this object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your first version is that class members are initialized in the order they declared, *not* in the order they appear in the initializer list.

So, when the members are defined in class

```
ros::Subscriber sub;
ros::NodeHandle nh;
```

and then initialized

```
NameSubscriber(std::string _topic, int queue_size)
: nh(ros::NodeHandle()),
sub(nh.subscribe(_topic, queue_size, &NameSubscriber::Callback, this))
```

you have `sub` initialized before `nh` is initialized, so `nh.subscribe(...)` is Undefined Behavior.

So, to make your first version work, you have to change the declaration order:

```
ros::NodeHandle nh;
ros::Subscriber sub;
```

Comment: Eugene, thank you for your reply, this modification makes the first version correct and executable, thank you for your help.